# How to copy an object in revit API using python

Tags: python, revit-api, revit, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

Is there a way I can copy a Filter Element Collector object?
For example, the original object is pointing at 0x000000000000156B and I want the copied object to be pointing at a different location so I can keep making modificacions without changing the original object.

Here's some code to illustrate my idea:

```
Col1 = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls)
#Some code to copy the object and assign it to Col2
Col2 = Col2.WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements() #Changing Col2 shouldn't change Col1.
```

I know there's no such method within the FilteredElementCollector class, but there should be a way to do this, right?
I also read about deepcopy but couldn't get it to work on Revit.

Any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Revit Element data can not exist outside of Revit document. You can't make a copy of a Revit element without actually having a second copy of the element inside the Revit model. For example, you need to duplication a wall element in Revit model (be aware of all the collision warnings this might cause), and then edit the second element

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I just thought maybe a collector could be copied. If I define two times the same collector I get two different FilteredElementCollector objects.
It'll be easier if instead of having to define the collector again I could just copy the one I already have, but, as you say, this may not be possible.

Comment: Every time you call a filtering method (e.g. `.OfCategory()` or `.OfClass()`) on a collector instance, they return a modified version of that instance. So even if you store a more generic collector in a variable, all subsequent calls to filtering methods will change the original collector as well

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the `FilteredElementCollector` method by wrapping it in a Python `list`. Then you can combine, refine, split, copy, sort - bascially do anything you want to it with all the ease that Python offers.

For your problem above, you could create the `FilteredElementCollector`, and spin it off into lists as required:

```
rawWalls = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls)

Col1 = list(rawWalls)
print 'There are',len(Col1),'wall types+instances in Col1'

Col2 = list(rawWalls.WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements())
print 'There are',len(Col2),'wall instances in Col2'
```

Comment: Hello there, thanks for your answer.
I don't think this achieves what I'm looking for. Col1 and Col2 still point at the same FilteredElementCollector object. If after you add Col3 =list(rawWalls.WhereElementIsElementType().ToElements()), you don't get any elements because the collector is already filtered out. My idea is to have a static collector (let's called it that), create a copy and then apply all filters to those copies so the original (static) collector remains unchaged.

Comment: Ah I see. So in that case Id just make a new `FilteredElementCollector` every time I needed it - they are blazingly quick. Sorry I couldnt be more help

Comment: No worries, I liked the idea of wrapping the collector in a python list. That'll come quite handy afterwards. And yes, it's quite fast and easy to define the collector all over again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you've already figured out, it's not possible to create a copy of a `FilteredElementCollector`.  However, you could create a functionally identical one by recording which methods are called on the original and duplicating those method calls when you need to make a copy. The class below does just that:

```py
class CopyableFilteredElementCollector(FilteredElementCollector):

    def __init__(self, doc):

        # Initialize the underlying FilteredElementCollector
        FilteredElementCollector.__init__(self, doc)

        # Save the document
        self._doc = doc

        # Calls to methods that constrain the FilteredElementCollector will be recorded here
        self._log = []

    def copy(self):

        # Create a brand new instance
        copy = CopyableFilteredElementCollector(self._doc)

        # Replay the log on the new instance
        for method_name, args in self._log:
            getattr(copy, method_name)(*args)

        # The copy now references the same document as the original,
        # and has had the same methods called on it
        return copy
```

We need to override each method that restrict the elements returned by the `FilteredElementCollector` to record its invocation in the log.  The most straightforward way to do that would be by defining override methods in the class body like this:

```py
    def OfCategory(self, category):

        # Add an entry to the log containing the name of the method that was called
        # and a tuple of its arguments that can be expanded with the splat operator
        self._log.append(('OfCategory', (category,)))

        # Call the original method
        FilteredElementCollector.OfCategory(self, category)

        # Return self just like the original method does 
        return self
```

Defining an override for every single method gets repetitive, so let's employ some metaprogramming voodoo instead:

```py
# Methods of FilteredElementCollector that constrain which elements it returns
constraint_methods = [
    'OfCategory',
    'OfClass',
    'WhereElementIsElementType',
    'WhereElementIsNotElementType',
    'WherePasses',
    # et cetera
]

# A factory function that produces override methods similar to the one defined above
def define_method(method_name):
    def method(self, *args):
        self._log.append((method_name, args))
        getattr(FilteredElementCollector, method_name)(self, *args)
        return self
    return method

# Create an override for each method and add it to the CopyableFilteredElementCollector class 
for method_name in constraint_methods:
    setattr(CopyableFilteredElementCollector, method_name, define_method(method_name))
```

I won't go as far as to claim that my approach is a good idea, but it's an option if your use case requires making copies of a `FilteredElementCollector` rather than creating new ones from scratch.